# vim: insert word with vim-surround

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, surround

I use [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) vim plugin.
when I write a latex source for make a word to `\bf` similar to

```
hello w*orld
```

( * is the cursor position)
I use

```
ysiw}a\bf<space>
```

and get

```
hello {\bf *world}
```

exist a more simple way? or how I can insert `\bf` automatically?

Comment: I know it's a bit off topic, but you should rather use `\textbf{foo}` instead of `{\bf foo}`,http://chenfuture.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/dos-and-donts-when-typesetting-a-document/

Answer (score 5):

I solved added this in my ~/.vimrc

```
let g:surround_42 = "{\\bf \r}"
```

and call over the word in normal mode

```
ysiw*
```

#### EDIT

is valid for the complete line with

```
yss*
```